# Using RED5 to record video stream

Tags: java, eclipse, red5, recorder

First of all - My English is very bad! so I hope you will understand what i'm asking...

I'm having difficulties in understanding how to use red5 to record stream from the client webcam onto the server side. I have red5 installed on a remote unix server, and i want to enable the users in my website to record stream from their webcam and store it on the server.

I have knowledge in javascript/php/java, and I know that I need to RTFM. I did try to search for some helpful information but i couldn't find any leads regarding my question.

Could you please help me with the first steps like how to connect to the remote server (I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you to take a look to [openmeeting](http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/) ,it's open source and use RED5 as media streaming server, and provides recording feature from client, and many other interesting features related to webcam.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look it up. If you know any good tutorials for red5 recorder please share them with me :)